Pine Script; I want to put a triangle on top of a bar when there has been 3 consective bars in the same direction
the below code is putting a triangle over all the bars, i only want it when there has been at least 3 bars in the same direction? What am i doing wrong?
//@version=5
indicator("Triangle Above Bars", overlay=true)

// Define the number of bars in a row required for the triangle
consecutiveBars = 3

// Calculate the number of bars in the current direction
barsInDirection = ta.valuewhen(close > close[1], consecutiveBars[1], 1)

// Check if there have been enough bars in a row
enoughBarsInRow = barsInDirection >= consecutiveBars

// Plot the triangle above the third bar in a row
plotshape(enoughBarsInRow ? high : na, title="Triangle", location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small)

I want the triangle to be on top of the bar when there has been 3 or more bars in the same direction. At the minute there is a triangle on top of every bar.
I think its because it thinks each bar is consecutive and there is no condition for bars in the same direction, but i cant get it to work.

What was your thought process when you write this code? How is barsInDirection calculated?
